# Hydration failing on nextJS Vercel project

Tags: dom, next.js, hydration

Error message shown below.

On the NextJS page: "While rendering your application, there was a difference between the React tree that was pre-rendered (SSR/SSG) and the React tree that rendered during the first render in the Browser. The first render is called Hydration which is a feature of React."

In plain English, is this saying that the React that was first rendered, is different than the React that was rendered in the browser? Why would there be a difference? Why can't the browser simply render the React that was initially rendered?

Also on the NextJS page: "This can cause the React tree to be out of sync with the DOM and result in unexpected content/attributes being present."

OK, I'm not sure what the DOM is. Let me read about it online: "The Document Object Model (DOM) is the data representation of the objects that comprise the structure and content of a document on the web.  In Next.js specifically, the DOM is the hierarchical structure of HTML elements that make up a page."

Hm, OK. So if the 'React tree' is out of sync with the 'DOM'. How would I look up the structure of each, so that I can reconcile them?

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

Call Stack
throwOnHydrationMismatch
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (12507:0)
tryToClaimNextHydratableInstance
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (12520:0)
updateHostComponent
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (19902:0)
beginWork
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (21618:0)
HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (4164:0)
Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (4213:0)
invokeGuardedCallback
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (4277:0)
beginWork$1
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (27451:0)
performUnitOfWork
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26557:0)
workLoopSync
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26466:0)
renderRootSync
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26434:0)
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (25738:0)
workLoop
node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (266:0)
flushWork
node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (239:0)
MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline
node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (533:0)
```

I read NextJS docs, I read about the DOM, and tried to understand what I would need to change/fix.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you app is not loading properly because of a ***mismatch*** between the HTML generated by the server and the content generated by the client-side code during hydration.

Some of your data is being left out. Have a look at what you added to your current build. This might be the code causing the issue.

You can also delete your node modules and rerun "npm install" before pushing.

You can also ***disable*** hydration all together by setting the "***suppressHydrationWarning***" flag to "***true***".

For example:

```
function App(props) {
  return (
    <div suppressHydrationWarning={true}>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Note: disabling hydration warnings is a bad idea

Comment: You are right. Its is a bad idea, but it is an option.